# Can't install Websharper nuget

Tags: f#, nuget, websharper

When i'm trying to create a sitelet project, nuget fails on installing

> NuGet Package restore failed for project To2a1.PublicSite.WebSharper: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Michakun\AppData\Local\Temp\nuget\atxvmxdn.eba\tools\net40\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Web.dll'

Anyone knows why? I'm using visual studio 2013 update 4

Comment: Is your antivirus reporting IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Web.dll as an infected file and quarantining it while you're installing the package?

Comment: Nope and i downloaded de nupckg and this dll doesn't exists inside. Is deprecated?

Comment: The file `tools/net40/IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Web.dll` definitely exists in the nupkg (latest version is 2.5.130.67).